# How to replace the jQuery library set in the MasterPage, from a Content Page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have this problem
My project has a master page and content pages, I have in Master Page this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

but i need use this in only one content page

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
```

how I do work ?

Comment: Do you know anything about Master Pages? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333650/Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your Master Page, add a `ContentPlaceHolder` to wrap the jQuery library script:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="jqContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

On every single Content Page that uses the default library, you just ignore the `ContentPlaceHolder` - by not putting it on the page, because if it's there and it's empty, you'll have no jQuery library whatsoever.

For the page you need a different library, just do this:

```
<!-- This will replace the default contents set on the Master Page -->
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="jqContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply defined the js file link in your content page inside the Head content place holder and it will overload the previous one.

Comment: Just if the OP hasn't changed the default format of the MasterPage template.

Comment: Also, why would you consume bandwidth with useless stuff, like downloading a library and a second one just to ignore the previous? May sound cheap savings, but as far as the project grows...

Comment: I need to use the version 1.5.2 for the mask input, and the version 1.6.2 not work with her, and i get the project now, in other words I not have developed

Comment: But the way you are doing it, i think i might be very irritating for a developer to include js on every page. He needs it only one page so it is not gonna hurt the bandwidth etc.

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli The developer will need to add the JS library just to the pages where they need to load a different one. Otherwise the one set on the MasterPage will be loaded. Got it?

Comment: @BrunoCasali So for you the simple way to do it is to just include the other js file inside this page.

Comment: Yes @Irfan TahirKheli, I know but if i include in Content page, conflict happens with versions of jQuery plugin

Comment: on the same page you got another plugin as well?

Comment: Scenario: The pages share the same jQuery library, except for one page. And this script is being loaded on a Master Page. Solution: Wrap the script within a ContentPlaceHolder and replace it on the desired page. As far as you're not setting a different content anywhere, the one wrapped in the Master Page will be loaded. Simple as that.

Comment: By loading multiple jQuery libraries on a single page, without caring about conflicts, you'll ended up having issues like forms being submitted twice, to name just one problem. Some events will be attached multiple times. It's a totally mess and can be avoided.